# How to determine a Fun from a CallExpr is user defined function or built-in function in golang

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

Consider the case

```
package main

import "fmt"

func len(s []int) string {
    return "xyz"
}

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3}
    fmt.Println(len(s))
}
```

Here output will be 'xyz' as len([]int) function is declared by user.
My question is how to determine this len function is built-in or user defined from ast.
I've ast.CallExpr node of len(s)

How can I determine an ast.CallExpr is user defined function call or built-in function call in golang?

Comment: You should type-check the AST and then look at the function's package.